# R won't recognize data as numeric

Tags: r, excel, decimal, compatibility

since Excel's last update, R won't recognize my files as numeric; even the ones I used in the past. 
I believe the source of my problem is that my Excel is in french and has changed the default decimal point from "." to "," (but this has never caused a problem in the past 5 years).

---

To distill the source of the problem, I tried using just one column of data (both with . and ,) but R always gives me this error:

> "Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'"

Here is a sample of the data (saved as a data.csv file)

```
23.15
23.35
23.46
20.88
20.77
22.05
21.5
22.65
21.93
22.65
22.47
22.75
22.05
21.95
22.3
19.48
19.44
20.55
20.5
21.65
20.83
21.85
21.77
21.95
23.35
23.55
23.86
21.38
21.29
22.35
22.6
```

I have used both:

```
read.csv AND read.csv2 (read.csv2 is the way to go)
```

Once imported in R, this is what it looks like:

[image]

But when I ask

```
is.numeric(data)
```

I get

```
> [1] FALSE
```

If I try to coerce with:

```
as.numeric
```

I get

```
> Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I am really at loss here; this seems like such a bad but simple compatibility problem. Thanks for your help.

---

FYI, I've already done this troubleshooting:

- Converted all old "." to "," (otherwise Excel don't see them as numbers and neither does R.
- Changed the default language in Excel from French to English. Since I have a mac, I have only been able to change the "editing" not the default display language.
- My laptop's default language in English.

Comment: What is `class(data)`? R will read your data in as a data.frame, not a numeric vector. If you just want a vector, use `scan()`. Otherwise it's likely that `class(data[[1]])` is numeric already (you just need to extract the column from the data.frame). This doesn't seem to be related to Excel at all.

Comment: class(data) yields: [1]"data.frame".      scan(data) yields an error: "Error in scan(data) : 'file' must be a character string or connection".     How would I go about extracting the column from the data frame? Thanks!

Comment: P.S. YES you are right, class(class[[1]]) --> [1]"numeric" . but I still can't seem to read it.

Comment: You would use `scan()` rather than `read.csv`. But your data is in a data.frame which is file. That's now most imports works. The data.frame itself isn't numeric, but it's columns can be numeric.

Comment: You should specify how you're reading it and how is this problem manifesting in your code.

Comment: Hi, @MrFlick I tried using `scan(data)` . It worked to scan the file where I only had 1 column of data. But I I try to use the file with the metadata to inform my analyses I got this error message: "Error in scan(data) : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got : ''treat;time_chunk;min_max;temp'" 
So now I know my data itself is numeric, but I still can't to access it. thanks

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik, I am reading my data this way: `data <- read.csv2("data.csv", header=TRUE)` . It appears as "data" in RStudio. The problem manifests itself when I try to analyze the data. EXAMPLE (with dplyr and tidyr package) `mean_minmax <- 
  data %>%
  group_by(treat,time_chunk)%>%
  summarise(mean=mean("temp"),sd=sd("temp"),n=n())`
I don't know how to attach data in a comment, but I have 6 columns of metadata(alpha-numeric) and one of data. The ERROR that shows up is : _argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA. NAs introduced by coercion_ . Thanks

Comment: Please take stackoverflow tour and see how site works. Comments are generally not a good place to deposit code that should be part of your question.

Comment: Sounds like you need to start reading the documentation for all these functions you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. It turns out I was alternating between multiple issues:

1. It is primordial to use read.csv2 with my new Excel update.
2. with my version, decimal points MUST be "," for Excel to recognize as numeric (and R too. R will read "." in my version but not recognize as numeric")
3. In my `summarise()` function (with dplyr and tidyr packages)  I was mistakenly putting " " around the column name I wanted to get the mean from. Ex. `summarise(mean=mean("temp"))` (PROPER WAY=> `summarise(mean=mean(temp))`
4. I was not asking properly: `as.numeric(data[4])` function. As @MrFlick pointed, the data frame was not numeric, but asking: `as.numeric(data[[4]])` singled out the column's data. `as.numeric(data[,4])` also works.
5. Finally, the problem was not the latest Excel update, but my new operating system (High Sierra) that was not compatible with my Excel version (2011). I had to update to the 2016 version to have the file revert back to their initial "." format and essentially resolve reading issues with R.

Cheers!

Comment: You could use`read.table` and specify all parameters explicitly.